# Which coding trees you know about?

Tags: encoding

I have read and understood huffman coding to some extent.

I did some googling but was unable to find other coding TREES.

I need to make comparision of HuffMan coding TREE with other coding TREES.

All I need are names of coding trees and if u can provide there small description it would be really helpful..

regards,
Aqif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shannon-Fano was a predecessor of Huffman coding (Fano was Huffman's professor).

Hu-Tucker is another method.

Context tree weighting method (CTW) is a lossless compression and prediction algorithm.

WBTC (wavelet block tree coder) algorithm is used for image coding.

Block-zero tree coding (BZTC) algorithm is also used for image coding.

Some of these are in Wikipedia, and some from plain old Google searching.